# Tailwind UI theme

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, themes, tailwind-ui

I have access to tailwindui.com website for its templates and components in vue/react

Recently I was tryna get in depth with their code in templates:

https://tailwindui.com/templates/studio

this is the template I'm dealing with

when it comes to modifying the theme / colors in  the template what is the appraoch?
I tried doing alot of play arounds but none worked, this is the theme css file
what should I do to change the colors of background , texts and everything , I went to see source of implementations but it's like a dead lock

```
.typography {
  color: theme(colors.neutral.950);
  font-size: theme(fontSize.xl);
  line-height: theme(fontSize.xl[1].lineHeight);

  --shiki-color-text: theme(colors.white);
  --shiki-color-background: theme(colors.neutral.950);
  --shiki-token-constant: theme(colors.neutral.300);
  --shiki-token-string: theme(colors.neutral.400);
  --shiki-token-comment: theme(colors.neutral.500);
  --shiki-token-keyword: theme(colors.neutral.400);
  --shiki-token-parameter: theme(colors.neutral.400);
  --shiki-token-function: theme(colors.neutral.300);
  --shiki-token-string-expression: theme(colors.neutral.300);
  --shiki-token-punctuation: theme(colors.neutral.400);

  :where(.typography > *) {
    margin-top: theme(spacing.6);
    margin-bottom: theme(spacing.6);
  }

  /* Headings */
  :where(h2) {
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
    font-family: theme(fontFamily.display);
    font-variation-settings: theme(fontFamily.display[1].fontVariationSettings);
    font-size: theme(fontSize.2xl);
    line-height: theme(fontSize.2xl[1].lineHeight);
    margin-top: theme(spacing.16);
  }

  :where(h3) {
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
    font-family: theme(fontFamily.display);
    font-variation-settings: theme(fontFamily.display[1].fontVariationSettings);
    font-size: theme(fontSize.xl);
    line-height: theme(fontSize.xl[1].lineHeight);
    margin-top: theme(spacing.10);
  }

  :where(h2 + h3) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  /* Lists */
  :where(ul, ol) {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  :where(ul) {
    list-style-type: disc;
  }

  :where(ol) {
    list-style-type: decimal;
  }

  :where(li) {
    padding-left: theme(spacing.3);
    margin-top: theme(spacing.6);
  }

  :where(li)::marker {
    color: theme(colors.neutral.500);
  }

  :where(li > *),
  :where(li li) {
    margin-top: theme(spacing.4);
  }

  :where(ol > li)::marker {
    font-size: theme(fontSize.base);
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
  }

  /* Tables */
  :where(table) {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: theme(fontSize.base);
    line-height: theme(fontSize.base[1].lineHeight);
  }

  :where(th) {
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
  }

  :where(thead th) {
    padding-bottom: theme(spacing.6);
    border-bottom: 1px solid theme(colors.neutral.950);
  }

  :where(td) {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: theme(spacing.6);
    padding-bottom: theme(spacing.6);
    border-bottom: 1px solid theme(colors.neutral.950 / 0.1);
  }

  :where(:is(th, td):not(:last-child)) {
    padding-right: theme(spacing.6);
  }

  /* Code blocks */
  :where(pre) {
    display: flex;
    background-color: theme(colors.neutral.950);
    border-radius: theme(borderRadius.4xl);
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-top: theme(spacing.10);
    margin-bottom: theme(spacing.10);
    margin-left: calc(-1 * theme(spacing.6));
    margin-right: calc(-1 * theme(spacing.6));

    @screen sm {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }

  :where(pre code) {
    flex: none;
    padding: theme(padding.8) theme(padding.6);
    font-size: theme(fontSize.base);
    line-height: theme(lineHeight.8);
    color: theme(colors.white);

    @screen sm {
      padding: theme(spacing.10);
    }
  }

  /* <hr> */
  :where(hr) {
    border-color: theme(colors.neutral.950 / 0.1);
    margin-top: theme(spacing.24);
    margin-bottom: theme(spacing.24);
  }

  /* Inline text */
  :where(a) {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
    text-underline-offset: 0.15em;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
  }

  :where(strong) {
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);
  }

  :where(code:not(pre code)) {
    font-size: calc(18 / 20 * 1em);
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.semibold);

    &::before,
    &::after {
      content: '`';
    }
  }

  :where(h2 code, h3 code) {
    font-weight: theme(fontWeight.bold);
  }

  /* Figures */
  :where(figure) {
    margin-top: theme(spacing.32);
    margin-bottom: theme(spacing.32);
  }

  /* Spacing overrides */
  :where(.typography:first-child > :first-child),
  :where(li > :first-child) {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }

  :where(.typography:last-child > :last-child),
  :where(li > :last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
}
```